# How to automatically push scroll-bar when new item was added

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, overflow

Please check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93gz3u1L/10/). If you add items to the #scroll div, the scroll-bar is fixed - it just stays at the "beginning". What I want to achieve is to move scroll-bar automatically when a new item is being appended to the parent. Is it possible to do this via magic of CSS? :)) Or only JS gonna solve it?

Code:

HTML

```
<div id="scroll">
   <div class="addElement">FIRST</div>
   <div class="addElement"></div>
   <div class="addElement">LAST</div>
</div>
<button id="add">ADD NEW ELEMENT</button>
```

CSS

```
#scroll {
overflow: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
width: 200px;
height: 150px;
background: red;
position: relative;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

.addElement {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 55px;
  background: green;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

JS

```
var scroll = $('#scroll');
var addButton = $('#add');

var item = 1;
addButton.click(function() {
    scroll.append(`<div class="addElement">ITEM ${item}</div>`);
  item++;
});
```

Thank you for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your fiddle to demonstrate a jQuery method of doing this:

https://jsfiddle.net/93gz3u1L/11/

I just added the following using `scrollLeft` (You can remove the animation if needed):

```
addButton.click(function() {
    scroll.append(`<div class="addElement">ITEM ${item}</div>`);
  item++;
  scroll.animate({
    scrollLeft: scroll.get()[0].scrollWidth
  });
});
```

Comment: True! But I figured I would add a jQuery alternative, knowing that someone would probably add a css-only solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css Direction property, setted to rtf! (right to left)

```
 #scroll {
    ...
    direction: rtl;
}
```

but you will need to **prepend** the elem instead of append it to the parent.

https://jsfiddle.net/k6Lhv3u6/1/